# Dynamic function chaining in Clojure

Tags: clojure, functional-programming

Is there any idiomatic way to do some thing similar to what the -> macro does, but with a dynamic list of functions?

I.e. apply every function in a vector to the output of the last function (all functions take one argument)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the build-in [comp](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/comp) function. You will want something like:

```
(defn f [fns & args]
   (let [all-fns (apply comp (reverse fns))]
      (apply all-fns args)))
```

And use it like:

```
(f [+ -] 1 2 3)
; -6
```

Comment: As we're told that `fns` is a vector, prefer `rseq` to `reverse`?

Answer (score 3):

A typical idiom is

```
(reduce #(%2 %) init fns)
```

For example,

```
(reduce #(%2 %) 0 [inc #(* 40 %) inc inc]) 
;=> 42
```